# How to fit a 2d curve to a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have squares matrices of real values and I would like to fit low degree polynomials or other simple functions to them. Here is a toy example matrix:

```
M = [[ 0.63,  2.58,  8.7 , 18.17, 32.97],
     [ 3.97,  4.42, 11.9 , 19.88, 34.74],
     [ 7.75, 10.68, 14.11, 24.11, 34.99],
     [15.75, 10.86, 10.72, 24.99, 42.02],
     [16.57,  7.48, 16.91, 42.33, 48.43]]
```

I would like to fit a function so that when I give it `(i,j)` it computes a values that is approximately `M[i,j]`.

Is there some way in scipy or numpy (or any other python library) to do this?

Comment: Have you seen this on github? it looks like someone has already thought about 2d curve fitting -- https://gist.github.com/silgon/24b56f8ae857ff4ab397

Answer (score 2):

The built-in tool [RectBivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline) provides a smooth approximation to 2D grid data (smoothness controlled by the parameter `s`). However it seems you want a single simple formula that fits the data; and a spline isn't that. But you can build a least squares fit from basic principles, as follows (where I assume `M` is a NumPy 2D array):

```
degrees = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (2, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2)]   # degrees to use
row = np.arange(M.shape[0])
col = np.arange(M.shape[1])
basis = np.array([np.outer(row**deg[0], col**deg[1]).ravel() for deg in degrees])
coeffs = np.linalg.lstsq(basis.T, M.ravel(), rcond=None)[0]
fit = coeffs.dot(basis).reshape(M.shape)
```

Explanation:

1. The list `degrees` indicates what monomials are used in the model: here they are the constant `row**0 * col**0`, linear `row**1 * col**0` and `row**0 * col**1`, and quadratics.
2. `basis` is formed by evaluating these monomials on the square grid.
3. `lstsq` finds the least  squares fit to `M` by a linear combination of the basis elements.
4. `fit` is the reconstruction, obtained by combining the basis elements with the coefficients we found.

In this example, the coefficients are `[3.46017143,  1.26657143, -3.31471429,  0.38585714,  0.2627, 2.64942857]`, which means that the model is

```
3.46017143 + 1.26657143*row - 3.31471429*col + 0.38585714*row**2 + 0.2627*row*col + 2.64942857*col**2
```

The fit is reasonable, given the various sudden jumps in your data. E.g. that 7.48 in the last row of M is really hard to fit to anything, and there are other oddities there.

```
  [[ 3.46017143,  2.79488571,  7.42845714, 17.36088571, 32.59217143],
   [ 5.1126    ,  4.71001429,  9.60628571, 19.80141429, 35.2954    ],
   [ 7.53674286,  7.39685714, 12.55582857, 23.01365714, 38.77034286],
   [10.7326    , 10.85541429, 16.27708571, 26.99761429, 43.017     ],
   [14.70017143, 15.08568571, 20.77005714, 31.75328571, 48.03537143]]
```

This can be generalized to functions other than polynomials, by adding them to the `basis`: e.g. `np.outer(np.sin(row), np.cos(col)).ravel()` would add `sin(row)*cos(col)` term to the model.

(I do not call the variables x and y, because it's often confusing how the vertical-horizontal order of matrix coordinates is mapped to horizontal-vertical order of x-y coordinates.)

Comment: For 3D scatterplot, 3D surface plot and contour plotting my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537055/matplotlib-plot-surface-for-2-dimensional-multiple-linear-regression/45550881#45550881 has example Python code, this might be useful for your surface fitting visualization.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there was simple library function that might do more of this built in.